# Connecting vertex between different meshes

Tags: vertices

I need to connect two vertex coming from different meshes.. I tried selecting both and presing f, F, J but nothing happens.
How can I do this?

Highlitghted elements are the two meshes.

[image: hierarchy]

Comment: You cannot. You can edit multiple objects at once, but they cannot "interact" with each other so long as they are separate objects. You can make them one object by selecting both and pressing Ctrl+J (Join).

Comment: are your meshes part of different objects or are they all within the same object? If they are part of different object, as Christopher says, you can't bridge them

Comment: I think they come from two separated objects (see picture above)

Comment: @weirdgyn Definitely, when they are two separate entries on the same level in the outliner then they are two separate objects.

Comment: You might be better off focusing on *why* you need to do this.  Then, people can give answers to achieve that goal (whether it means simply joining meshes, or weird modifier stack craziness.)

Comment: uh... I need to create a wire !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by this:

1. select both objects -> press <kbd>CTRL-J</kbd>

[image]

2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> -> edit mode

[image]

3. Select the two vertices you want to join

[image]

4. Press <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

5. <kbd>Tab</kbd> -> object mode

[image]